# How to add custom button under the phone number field in one page checkout in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, custom-field, custom-button

I need to add a **button** under the **phone number** filed in the **shipping address** section in a one-page checkout and the button should be visible only when the user enters the phone number. Based on the entered number, I need to check the condition whether the button is visible or not. How to achieve this?. I already followed this link  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html but I did not know how to add button under the phone number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override checkout shipping address Phone component to show and control a custom Button under Phone filed.

I assume you are using a custom Module named   "**Company_MyModule**"   for this customisation.

Please create the followings files and follow the steps as describe below.

**step 1)**

Create **checkout_index_index.xml**
under  ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/***

**File :** *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                                      
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- the field you are customizing -->
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">                                                                    
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/js/form/telephone</item>
                                                                    <!-- add validation rules here-->
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="validate-phoneStrict" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- Assigning a new template -->
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/form/phone_button</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 2)**

Create the custom UI Component js file **telephone.js**
under
***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/form/***

**File** : *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/form/telephone.js*

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
],  function (_, uiRegistry, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';
   return Component.extend({       
        isShowPhoneButton: ko.observable(false),        
        showPhonePopUp: function (){
            alert("I am Clicked");
        },
        onUpdate: function(){
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            if(this.checkInvalid()){                                
                self.isShowPhoneButton(false);
            } else {                
                self.isShowPhoneButton(true);
            }
        }       
    });
});
```

**Step 3)**

Create the custom UI Component template file **phone_button.html**
under
***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/template/form***

**File** : *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/template/form/phone_button.html*

```
<!-- input field element and corresponding bindings -->
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',    
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" />
<!-- additional content -->
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
<button type="button" class="action" data-bind="click: showPhonePopUp, visible: isShowPhoneButton()">
     <span data-bind="i18n: 'My Button'">My Button</span>
</button>
```

**step 5)**

Run followings commands to refresh cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:f
```

## **NOTE:**

I added two validation class for checkout shipping address  phone number field. Those are "**required-entry**" and "**validate-phoneStrict**" in the layout XML  file *checkout_index_index.xml*. Please update the validation section as per your needs.

```
---------------------
---------------------
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="validate-phoneStrict" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
---------------------
---------------------
```

### <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Here is the Demo >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.But what is the use of Company_MyModule/js/form/element/telephone  file? and what I need to implement in this section?

Comment: <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/js/form/element/telephone</item> what to add in this section?

Comment: Yes as you nee to customise checkout shipping address  phone number section , you need to create a custom component. I create the custom  component telephone.js under Company_MyModule/js/form/element/ ("Company_MyModule" is the module name).

Comment: can you post your telephone.js for my reference?

Comment: Please check my updated ans. Thank you.

Comment: You saved my day.Thank you very much.How can i validate the telephone number already exist in my my database table(or suggest me, how to to make server call from knockout js to validate phone number which already exist in my list).My actual scenario is i need to verify otp only for the new telephone numbers.For already verified OTP number i will not want to verify OTP. Can you please suggest any idea or sample code to achieve this.

Comment: This is a separate requirement. If you need to verify OTP at registration step then you may look for such module or Can Build a custom Module.- Thank you

Comment: I posted question-related to the above scenario, can you please help me out. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300634/how-to-pass-value-from-template-html-to-js-in-magento-2-knockout-js-when-complet

Comment: Can we custom block after the Phone Number and before the Shipping Method title?