# In magento 2, how to to make server call from knockout js to validate phone number in checkout page which already exist in my list?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, validation

How can i validate the telephone number already exist in my my database table(or suggest me, **how to to make server call from knockout js to validate phone number** which already exist in my list).My actual scenario is i need to verify otp only for the new telephone numbers.For already verified OTP number i will not want to verify OTP. Can you please suggest any idea or sample code to achieve this.

For reference:[How to add custom button under the phone number field in one page checkout in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298008/how-to-add-custom-button-under-the-phone-number-field-in-one-page-checkout-in-ma)