# How to pass value from template.html to js in magento 2 knockout js when complete entering the input field?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, custom, knockoutjs, knockout

1) I need to pass the phone number value to the *telephone.js* when complete entering the number before the button click.

2)Below the phone number field, I added the OTP input field (i added it in the same phone_button.html template it is the correct way to add it or do I need to manage in the layout?) after entering the OTP, I need to pass phone number and OTP to telephone.js file when clicking the submit button.

[image]

**phone_button.html**

```
<!-- input field element and corresponding bindings -->
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
        value: value,
        valueUpdate: 'keyup',    
        hasFocus: focused,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
        }" />
    <!-- additional content -->
    <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
    <button type="button" class="action" data-bind="click: showPhonePopUp.bind($data), visible: isShowPhoneButton()">
         <span data-bind="i18n: 'Send OTP'">Send OTP</span>
    </button>

    <fieldset class="fieldset" >
        <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="otp: value" />
        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary" >
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Submit'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="secondary">
                <a class="action remind">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Resend OTP'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

**telephone.js**

```
define([
        'underscore',
        'uiRegistry',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'mage/storage',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
    ],  function (_, uiRegistry, ko, Component,modal, storage, urlBuilder, fullScreenLoader) {
        'use strict';
       return Component.extend({       
            isShowPhoneButton: ko.observable(false), 

            showPhonePopUp: function (){debugger;


            },

            onUpdate: function(){debugger;
                var self = this;
                this._super();


                if(this.checkInvalid()){                                
                    self.isShowPhoneButton(false);
                } else {                
                    self.isShowPhoneButton(true);
                }

            }       
        });
    });
```

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                                      
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- the field you are customizing -->
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">                                                                    
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/js/form/telephone</item>
                                                                    <!-- add validation rules here-->
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="validate-phoneStrict" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- Assigning a new template -->
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/form/phone_button</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```