# How to show validation or disable checkout until the phone number get verified with otp in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, custom-options, validation, messages

I am verifying the phone number through OTP in Magento 2 one page checkout. when the user clicks the place order button before the phone number gets verified, I need to show a validation message to verify the phone number.

I have created the OTP verification module for the phone number based on the below link:
[How to add custom button under the phone number field in one page checkout in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298008/how-to-add-custom-button-under-the-phone-number-field-in-one-page-checkout-in-ma/298422?noredirect=1#comment430486_298422)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve your goal.

For example, you can try with Plugin:

app/code/Vendor/Checkout/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="verify_phone_validation" type="Vendor\Checkout\Plugin\Payment\VerifyPhoneValidation"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Your Plugin:

```
public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    PaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
    $cartId,
    PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    //Your custom logic

    if ($customer->isVerifiedPhone()) {
                throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                    __(
                        "The order wasn't placed. "
                        . "You need to verify the phone number before placing order"
                    )
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: when is the plugin gets called?.when click on place order button?